# My WPF app has a few graphically intensive features like glow effects. When I run this app on my surface pro 6, it's very slow

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, animation

My WPF app has a few graphically intensive features like glow effects (coloured DropShadowEffect) and animations for buttons etc. When I run this app on my surface pro 6, it's very slow. Animation's are jagged and UI takes a while to respond. I'd like to add a setting to the app where users can disable these graphics features, but I'm not sure how I can achieve this when all the features are written into the XML of my app, rather than the C#.

Here's an example of a control with these effects:

```
<Border Background="White" CornerRadius="25,0,25,0">
  <Border.Effects>
    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="0" Color="Blue"/>
  </Border.Effects>
  <Border.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation To="1.025" Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetName="Scaler" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"/>
          <DoubleAnimation To="1.025" Duration="0:0:0.2" Storyboard.TargetName="Scaler" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"/>
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Border.Triggers>
</Border>
```

I'm also a little confused about why it's so slow. Computer resources are at 10% CPU usage, 20% RAM usage, 4% GPU usage and I've set the program's priority to real-time. This device is capable of running some games without any issues, so why can't it handle this?

Any ideas about how I can disable these features during runtime or get the app to run smoothly on slower devices would be appreciated.

**Edit / Solution:**

I figured out the issue, for any people facing it in the future, it's definitely the glow effects that are causing it. I removed the one from the MainWindow and my app became significantly faster. To control their appearance with an in-app setting, create a bool setting, then using the example above, replace this:

```
<Border.Effects>
  <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="0" Color="Blue"/>
</Border.Effects>
```

with this:

```
<Border.Style>
  <Style TargetType="Border">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static YourNamespace:Properties.Default}, Path=PerformanceMode, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="Effect"> 
          <Setter.Value>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="0" Color="Blue" RenderingBias="Performance"/>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</Border.Style>
```

and add this to the top of the XML file:

```
xmlns:Properties="clr-namespace:YourNamespace.Properties"
```

Comment: Wow, that's interesting.  I can only imagine that the Surface Pro simply lacks the graphic accelerator features that are present in most desktop machines.  A pity, considering the price of the thing.

Comment: Yeah it's unfortunate, especially when you try use programs like Windows Whiteboard and they're slow too.